# Enter key not registering on other computers

Tags: raspbian

I keep all of my files on a flash drive so that I can move them from computer to computer. When editing `.txt` files on my Pi, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key acts perfectly normal; showing this on the screen:

```
This is
a Test.
```

When I open up the same file on my Windows 10 *in Notepad*, it shows this:

```
This isa Test.
```

As if <kbd>Enter</kbd> never registered in the file. However, when I open up the file in *Notepad++*, it looks like the first example.

I upgraded from a Pi 1 to a Pi 2 a few weeks ago, and I have had the same problem on both systems. I also upgraded from Windows 8 to 10 a while ago, also with no change.

Does anyone know what's going on here, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect is the result of the way line endings are handled in Windows vs. Linux. Windows uses a carriage return and line feed while Linux uses a line feed only. You can read more about this [here](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-great-newline-schism/). The reason for the differing results between notepad and notepadd++ is that [notepad++](http://www.larshaendler.com/2013/06/10/notepad-unix-to-dos-line-endings/) is a little more sophisticated in its handling of line endings (basically it is aware of the difference and can be setup to work with both styles).

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891076/how-to-convert-windows-end-of-line-in-unix-end-of-line-cr-lf-to-lf) explains how to convert Windows line endings to Linux line endings, and this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/71507/convert-unix-line-endings-to-windows) explains the conversion from Linux to Windows line endings.

To covert line endings on your Pi install the dos2unix package, by doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```

You can read the Man page (documentation) for the unix2dos command with the following command:

```
man dos2unix
```

If you are using git, there are [config settings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) that will control the line endings